# ANTLR4: get subtoken's type

Tags: java, antlr

I'm building parser for my grammar using ANTLR4 and want to get type of token inside of a other token if that's possible.
For example:

```
NUMBER_LITERAL
    : INT_LITERAL
    | FLOAT_LITERAL;
```

when I want to build AST for such rule I can get that it's `NUMBER_LITERAL` using `Token::getType` but if I then want to decide if it's `INT_LITERAL` or `FLOAT_LITERAL` I can't seem to find any way to do so.

Is this possible or do I have to create parser rule for `NUMBER_LITERAL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tokens don't have subtokens in ANTLR, so there's no way to do what you want with a token. I should also point out that if `NUMBER_LITERAL`, `INT_LITERAL` and `FLOAT_LITERAL` are all lexer rules (as opposed to `INT_LITERAL` and `FLOAT_LITERAL` being fragments), then either `NUMBER_LITERAL` can never match or `INT_LITERAL` and `FLOAT_LITERAL` can never match, depending on the order in which they are defined.

What I would do is to have `INT_LITERAL` and `FLOAT_LITERAL` as tokens and then make `NUMBER_LITERAL` a parser rule. That way you can check whether a literal is a float or int either by using labelled alternatives or by just checking which of `INT_LITERAL()` or `FLOAT_LITERAL()` does not return `null`.